# Считаются ли умлауты диакритическими знаками?

Tags: другое

Понимаю, что форум не по немецкому языку, однако понятие диакритический знак не относится к немецкому языку, поэтому хотелось бы знать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Само понятие "диакритического знака" далеко не однозначно и не очевидно. Разбираться в деталях на этом форуме - это путь в дебри. Поэтому лучше уточнить, для чего понадобилось утверждение.

Если просто для систематики упомянуть или там в плане издательско-типографском, для классификации знаков, то без проблем причисляйте к диакритике.

Ну а с точки зрения немецкого языка, то "знаки с двумя точками" традиционно рассматриваются как самостоятельные графемы, а не как "A, U или O c точками". 
Ситуация примерно та же, что и в русском для буквы Й. Значок над И ("кратка") - это диакритика или нет? Для шрифтодизайнера или историка языка - скорее да, чем нет. Для всех остальных - Й - самостоятельная буква (графема), разве что несколько оригинального начертания.

Comment: Когда буква меняет свое произношение, это уже диакритический язык. А данном случае перегласовка (Umlaut с немецкого так переводится). Также в романских языках –– итальянском, французском, испанском –– часто встречаются диакритические знаки, которые, насколько я знаю,  меняют произношение.

Comment: >Когда буква меняет свое произношение, это уже диакритический язык.     
  
Две точки над буквой ї в украинском - диакритический знак? А одна над i?
А во французском? Турецком?

Понимаете, всякое ко многому обязывающее утверждение надлежит осмысливать раньше чем применять.

Answer (score 0):

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА

Диакритические знаки - различные надстрочные и подстрочные знаки, применяемые  на письме не как самостоятельные обозначения звуков, а для изменения или уточнения значения других знаков.

Диакритики наиболее широко используются в языках, имеющих латинский алфавит. Это связано с тем, что в классическом латинском языке не было шипящих звуков, носовых гласных, палатализованных (смягчённых) гласных, которые имелись или развились в других языках, особенно неродственных.

Умлаут (нем. Umlaut), — диакритический ФОНЕТИЧЕСКИЙ знак, указывающий на  изменившееся («смягчившееся») произношение некоторых гласных ä, ö  ü  в немецком языке, а также в  некоторых других языках, использующих германскую письменность. Это надстрочное двоеточие.

При невозможности использования диакритических знаков буквы с умлаутом в немецком языке традиционно заменяются на диграфы: ä на «ae», ö на «oe», ü на «ue». В ряде имён собственных пишутся всегда диграфы, но не буквы с умляутом, например, Гёте — Goethe.

У одного (по форме) знака может быть много названий, употребляемых в зависимости от того, о каком языке идёт речь: так, одно и то же надстрочное двоеточие применительно к немецкому языку будет названо «умляут» (в последнее время также «умлаут»), ко французскому — «трема», а к русскому — чаще всего просто «две точки». Однако в разных языках знак "две точки" может иметь различное значение.

Comment: Уже понял, что являются.